# send email with php mail works sometimes ubuntu 17.04 and php 7 + postfix

Tags: php, postfix, mail, php7

I have a issue sending email with *postfix* + *php7*. I press button to send email and I get it,  but sometimes mail is not arrived, clicking in  the same button. After a while or few minutes I'm tried to send email and works.

This is the php code to send email on the server side, I'm using ajax.

```
 $message = "<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>

                    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
                    <style> 

                        .dataClass{
                            font-size: 14px;
                            font-weight: bold;
                        }</style>

                </head>
                <body>
                    test email dealer processing
                </body>
            </html>
            ";


            $headers =                   
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n".
            'From: ScanChex <admin@scanchex.net>' . "\r\n".
                        'Reply-To: ScanChex <admin@scanchex.net>' ."\r\n";




            $sent  = mail($email, 'Welcome To ScanChex dealer ', $message, $headers);
```

This is the response when email is sent ok in */var/log/mail.log*

```
****Aug 27 00:28:46 localhost postfix/smtp[9308]: 0C0C9122A00: to=<delstonetest@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
[108.177.98.27]:25, delay=0.27, delays=0/0.01/0.07/0.19, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1503793726 v37si5208238plg
.629 - gsmtp)****
```

This is the response in */var/log/mail.log* when emails is not sent

```
**Aug 27 00:31:37 localhost postfix/local[9358]: 6F8BC122A09: to=<scanchex@scanchex.net>, orig_to=<www-data@scanchex.net>,
 relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Aug 27 00:31:37 localhost postfix/qmgr[27663]: 6F8BC122A09: removed**
```

I don't understand why "to" change to `<www-data@scanchex.net>` or `<scanchex@scanchex.net>` when is the same process.